# Logging chokes on BlockingIOError: write could not complete without blocking

Tags: python-3.x, python-logging

I recently ported my scripts from 2.x to 3.x. During production runs through automation (rundeck) we are seeing errors caused by the logger not handling blocking I/O. Any ideas how to resolve would be great.

- Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
- Python 3.6.7

```
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 998, in emit
    self.flush()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 978, in flush
    self.stream.flush()
BlockingIOError: [Errno 11] write could not complete without blocking
```

Answer (score 4):

I was getting the same error on CI builds. It looks like it was a capacity issue with the output stream. After reducing the log output, the errors went away.

Comment: There should be a more permanent solution to resolve this !

Answer (score 1):

I recently faced the error while building my `Docker` image using `docker-compose` in CI and I found one Workaround maybe that will help someone:

the Error:

```
BlockingIOError: [Errno 11] write could not complete without blocking
```

if you do not want to lose any logs , you can send all the logs to file and save it as an artifact , tested on `Bamboo` and `Jenkins`:

```
docker-compose build --no-cache my_image > myfile.txt
```

if you do not want the logs:

```
docker-compose build --no-cache my_image > /dev/null
```