# App deploy fails on GCP App Engine (GAE) flexible when specifying engines.node version

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud

```
gcloud --project my-project-id app deploy app.yaml
```

fails on GAE Flex when I specify a engines.node version in package.json
but succeeds when I remove it from the package.json, which is contradictory to the https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/runtime documentation.

I have specified

```
"engines": {
    "node": "16.x"
  }
```

in my package.json

The error I ultimately get is:

```
ERROR: gcloud crashed (IOError): [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable
```

It seems this error is transient as on vary rare occasions in the past 24 hours, the app deploy succeeded.

Google folks, can you confirm the problem is on your side ?
I am deploying on GAE Flex in asia-southeast2-a (Jakarta)

Thanks

Below a more complete log trace

```
BUILD
Starting Step #0
Step #0: Pulling image: gcr.io/gcp-runtimes/nodejs/gen-dockerfile@sha256:770f37e7042652138c7dac203fc35ef0218002515ddd9f311db1c6c54d6816aa
Step #0: gcr.io/gcp-runtimes/nodejs/gen-dockerfile@sha256:770f37e7042652138c7dac203fc35ef0218002515ddd9f311db1c6c54d6816aa: Pulling from gcp-runtimes/nodejs/gen-dockerfile
Step #0: Digest: sha256:770f37e7042652138c7dac203fc35ef0218002515ddd9f311db1c6c54d6816aa
Step #0: Status: Downloaded newer image for gcr.io/gcp-runtimes/nodejs/gen-dockerfile@sha256:770f37e7042652138c7dac203fc35ef0218002515ddd9f311db1c6c54d6816aa
Step #0: gcr.io/gcp-runtimes/nodejs/gen-dockerfile@sha256:770f37e7042652138c7dac203fc35ef0218002515ddd9f311db1c6c54d6816aa
Step #0: Checking for Node.js.
Finished Step #0
Starting Step #1
Step #1: Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor@sha256:f87c11770a4d3ed33436508d206c584812cd656e6ed08eda1cff5c1ee44f5870
Step #1: INFO[0000] Removing ignored files from build context: [node_modules .dockerignore Dockerfile npm-debug.log yarn-error.log .git .hg .svn app.yaml] 
Step #1: INFO[0000] Downloading base image gcr.io/google-appengine/nodejs@sha256:721ce182842495a610589261688f1abc1801c915a7e24880fa15af9e9d725459 
Step #1: INFO[0017] Taking snapshot of full filesystem...        
Step #1: INFO[0026] Using files from context: [/workspace]       
Step #1: INFO[0026] COPY . /app/                                 
Step #1: INFO[0026] Taking snapshot of files...                  
Step #1: INFO[0026] RUN /usr/local/bin/install_node '16.x'       
Step #1: INFO[0026] cmd: /bin/sh                                 
Step #1: INFO[0026] args: [-c /usr/local/bin/install_node '16.x'] 
Step #1:   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
Step #1:                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 30.8M  100 30.8M    0     0  68.9M      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 68.9M
Step #1:   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
Step #1:                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  4035  100  4035    0     0  35238      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 35394
Step #1: node-v16.13.0-linux-x64.tar.gz: OK
Step #1: Installed Node.js v16.13.0
Step #1: INFO[0028] Taking snapshot of full filesystem...        
Step #1: INFO[0030] Adding whiteout for /nodejs/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-install-checks/CHANGELOG.md 
Step #1: INFO[0030] Adding whiteout for /nodejs/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/os-tmpdir 
Step #1: INFO[0030] Adding whiteout for /nodejs/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npmlog/CHANGELOG.md 
Step #1: INFO[0030] Adding whiteout for /nodejs/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/lodash.uniq 
(...)
ERROR: gcloud crashed (IOError): [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Thanks

[Update] I have upgrade the gcloud-sdk and the error message is a little different now, I get a

**[Errno 11] write could not complete without blocking**

in the middle of the long logging stream generated by the gcloud app deploy command.

Following the advise of other developers (related to python lib issues, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54185874/logging-chokes-on-blockingioerror-write-could-not-complete-without-blocking) I found a workaround by adding the `--no-user-output-enabled` flag to the gcloud app deploy command. This prevents the error from happening.

But this is a temp workaround and I hope the GCP team will fix the issue in the CLI library.

Comment: You'll be more likely to elicit a useful response from the community if you will provide more information about your hardware/software environment. Generally, the more specific, the better.

Comment: As of Nov. 20th 2021, visiting [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/runtime) page reveals a green banner towards the top claiming that Node.js 16 is in **preview**.  While it seems like `16.x.x`  is the current Node LTS (more on that [here](https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases)), this shift from `14.x.x` to `16.x.x` only happened a month ago and AEF might need some time to catch up.  Are you still having these intermittent issues?  If you are, do you make use of features only found in `16.x.x` or could you fall back on `14.x.x` (which is in maintenance until 2023)?

Comment: yes, I still do get these transient [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable errors...

Comment: [Update] I have upgrade the gcloud-sdk and the error message is a little different now, I get a 
**[Errno 11] write could not complete without blockingy** 
in the middle of the long logging stream generated by the gcloud app deploy command.
Following the advise of other developers (related to python lig issues) I found a workaround by adding the `--no-user-output-enabled` flag to the gcloud app deploy command. This prevents the error from happening and the app deploys without issues. But this is a temp workaround and I hope the GCP team will fix the issue in the CLI library.